# matlab - can I use roipoly to get data from a scatter plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter-plot

I want to select data using a polygonal shape. I understand roipoly does that for 'images'. is there something like this for scatter plots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use data brushing to mark data on a scatter plot then extract it to the workspace. Look for the little brush symbol at the top of a figure window.

See [Marking up graphs with Data Brushing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/data_analysis/brh7_p3-1.html) from Matlab, and [Accessing plot brushed data](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/accessing-plot-brushed-data/) from the very useful Undocumented Matlab.

If you want to draw a complex polygon, you can use impoly and inpoly:

```
X = rand(200, 2);
scatter(X(:,1), X(:,2));

h = impoly();
% now you go and position the polygon, control returns once you've 'finsished' with it '

nodes = getPosition(h);
selected_indices = inpoly(X, nodes);
```

Comment: wow! 'inpoly' is great. (must be downloaded from http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10391-fast-points-in-polygon-test)

Comment: you can also use the existing matlab function "inpolygon"

Comment: thanks for the link to matlabcentral; upon googling inpoly I had ended up at a different Matlab function with the same name (which wouldn't work with the above example)